# What is LdaKeyedProperty in V8 byte code?

Tags: javascript, v8

This is a sample V8 byte code.

984 E> 00000318BA8792D3 @   41 : 29 02 07          LdaKeyedProperty a0, [7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ld" means "load" (from memory)
"a" means "to the accumulator register" (as most bytecodes)
"KeyedProperty" means it's for JS code like `obj[index]` (as opposed to a "named property" like `obj.foo`).